# git-tfs returns "(401) unauthorized" error when cloning a repository

Tags: git-tfs

I used git-tfs to work with a TFVC repository. I started working on other project and the project's code is hosted on a different server.

Now I get errors when I try to clone the repository.

```
git tfs clone http://tfs-server:8080/tfs $/CompanyName/Dev
```

It prompts me to enter the credentials twice. Then it shows an error.

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs-server:8080/tfs.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I've double checked it is a correct url. I can connect with Visual Studio and with a browser.

I've double checked it is a correct password and username. I can log in with this credentials in a browser.

I am able to clone the code from a different server on my machine.

The server is Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013. My git-tfs version is

```
git-tfs version 0.21.0.0 (TFS client library 12.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)
```

I've found a few questions with a similar error and tried the answers. So these are things I tried to do:

- Logging off from this server in Visual Studio's browser;
- Cleaning Internet Explorer cache
- Deleting C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache folder;
- Adding tfs server to local intranet security zone in Internet Explorer.

This is the debug output:

```
git tfs clone http://tfs-server:8080/tfs $/CompanyName/Dev --debug

Command run:git tfs clone http://tfs-server:8080/tfs $/CompanyName/Dev --debug
No authors file used.
git-tfs version 0.21.0.0 (TFS client library 12.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)
git command: Starting process: git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/UserName/Dev/.git/
git command time: [00:00:00.0660000] init
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs-server:8080/tfs. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.GetInstanceId()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.get_InstanceClientCacheDirectory()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsObject)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.CreateServiceProxy(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.FindServiceLocation(String serviceType, String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.VsCommon.TfsHelperBase.EnsureAuthenticated()
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.EnsureTfsAuthenticated()
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitRepository.CreateTfsRemote(RemoteInfo remote, String autocrlf, String ignorecase)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Init.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Clone.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath, String gitRepositoryPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 args)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 unparsedArgs)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args)
TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfs-server:8080/tfs.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

What can I do to get my git-tfs flow back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added collection name to the server's url and it worked.

The correct command was:

```
git tfs clone http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/collectionName $/CompanyName/Dev
```

Although the command in the question worked for the previous server.

Comment: Hi there, when you refer to 'CollectionName' where can i find this exactly? Im having the same issue :( thanks

Comment: It is Team Project Collection. If you have web access, you can find in in the url after /tfs/ part after redirects are made.

Comment: @burrows111 Also it's in the left column in the Connect to Team Foundation Server window ([screenshot](http://content.screencast.com/users/filhit/folders/Jing/media/b337d520-3a41-4078-bc95-ccfeac74cbc4/2015-07-10_0855.png))

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, sadly no I still get 401, intact i was submitting the 'CollectionName' in the Git repo URL, been stuck on this for  months and the company i work for are stumped :o